# What is the source for men covering their heads?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, men-male, head-covering

I remember learning (but don't remember where) that men are required *d'rabbanan* to cover their heads at least when saying *b'rachot*, but practically speaking people just cover them all the time.  (That makes sense; you never know when you're going to experience something that calls for an unplanned *b'racha*.)  I was talking tonight with somebody who thought wearing a head-covering is strong *minhag* but not *halacha*, and he asked me for a source.  I said I didn't know but I know a place to find out.

What is the actual *halacha* for when men have to cover their heads, is it *d'rabbanan* as I remember learning, and what is its source?

(The topic came up because he's shopping for a school for his oldest child and he's found schools with different policies about *kippot*.)

Comment: _"Minhag Yisroel Torah Hi."_

Comment: @ezra yes, but is that how *this* happened, or is this independently required per *halacha*?

Comment: I don't think the question is quite a duplicate (the other asks where *in torah* it says to wear a kippah), but the answer there goes beyond the question and answers mine, so I'll mark as a dupe.  Thanks @ezra for finding it for me.